# What is the minimal number of states for the DFA?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

> Let the regular expression $R = ((a^*\cup \emptyset \cup \varepsilon^*)^*b)^*$ above $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d\}$. What is the minimal number of states for a DFA accepting this regex?

1. $1$
2. $2$
3. $4$
4. $5$ or more

So for my understanding, this regex is equivalent to $(a^*b)^*$. I was able to build the following DFA, nevertheless, I know the **answer is $2$**. How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Your simplified regex is ok. Your automaton is not correct. You can have any number of consecutive $b$. BTW, you do not tell which is the initial state.  And you do need 3 states if you have an explicit failure state.

Comment: Follow the algorithms you've seen in class; this is a rote exercise. (Note, though, that not all definitions of DFA require the existence of q_fail. Your material should be consistent about that. Hopefully.)

Comment: @babou, so basically this regex can be translated to $L = \{a^nb^n : n \ge 0\}$. I still need the third state "q_fail" in order to handle the characters $c,d$, so I am still not sure how can it can be reduced to $2$ states..

Comment: @Elimination The regexp certainly doesn't translate to $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ because thats the canonical non-regular language.

Comment: Oh right.. my bad.

Comment: What the regex says is that you can have any string that is empty or ends with a $b$. But you need 2 states to distinguish whether you are allowed to accept, having just read a $b$ or not, plus a third state for failure when you read $c$ or $d$. But it is often the case that the failure state and corresponding transitions are left implicit. Try to understand why the regex reads as I said.

Answer (score 2):

Your $\Sigma=\{a,b,c,d\}$ so you have to add at least one dead state. The DFA is:
[image]

Comment: Some authors have an implicit dead state by defining a DFA as one in which each state has at most one transition per symbol. Since 3 isn't an option, I guess whoever set the exercise in the quesion subscribes to that viewpoint.

Comment: Interesting. However you can obtain the correct answer by discard. As we already generated a DFA with 3 states we can discard alternative 3 and 4. Alternative 1 is not possible because the DFA of one state denote a different language. So I would mark alternative 2 and ask an explanation from my teacher later haha.